# Delete row with a complex if

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a query where it deletes duplicates from table where the Access column value is 1 - 5, but always take the highest number but if it's 5 then that should be the lowest, because of how they designed the database. but 5 have no access.(5 should have been 0 in my opinion.)

So there is an ID column and an Access column, if there are more than 1 IDs, then delete the ID with the lowest Access value. But remember treat 5 as 0 or lowest.
[image]

So I thought something like:

```
Delete from [table]
Where [ID] > 1
AND [Access] = (CASE [Access] 
    WHEN Access = 1 THEN ____ <----'Do nothing')
    ...
    WHEN Access = 5 THEN ____ <----'Do Delete')
```

That is where I struggle. How would I check ID, and see which Access is the highest and delete all the lowest if they exist. Remember, if it's 5 then 4 is actually higher so delete 5.

So confusing!

Comment: Is it MS SQL Server query?

Comment: Step 1 - write the select query to define your duplicates. Step 2, modify that to perform the delete

Comment: Image added and yes MSSQL

Comment: When you say "more than 1 ID", what do you mean?  More than one *row with the same ID*?  Can you add to your user table example, (8, 5), i.e. a row that has only 5 as its access (which means it should be kept, right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply modulo 5 to the Access column, you will get the following transformation:

```
1 % 5 = 1
2 % 5 = 2
3 % 5 = 3
4 % 5 = 4
5 % 5 = 0
```

As you can see, 5 yields the lowest result, others remain unchanged – seems the proper ranking of privileges for your case. With that in mind, I would probably try the following method:

```
DELETE FROM u
FROM dbo.UserTable AS u
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ID, MAX(Access % 5) AS Access
  FROM dbo.UserTable
  GROUP BY ID
) AS keep
  ON u.ID = keep.ID
 AND u.Access % 5 = keep.Access
WHERE i.ID IS NULL
;
```

The subquery returns a set of IDs with Access values to keep. The main query anti-joins the target table to that set to determine which rows to delete.

This method is somewhat specific to your particular situation: it may not work correctly after extending the current set of valid values for `Access`. As an alternative, you could use CASE, as others suggested, that would certainly be more flexible. However, I would actually suggest you add an `AccessRank` column to the `Access` table to indicate which privilege is higher or lower than others.

That would make your DELETE query more complex but you wouldn't need to adapt it every time new `Access` values are introduced (you'd just need to define proper ranking *in your data*):

```
DELETE FROM u
FROM dbo.UserTable AS u
INNER JOIN dbo.Access AS a
  ON u.Access = a.ID
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT u.ID, MAX(a.AccessRank) AS AccessRank
  FROM dbo.UserTable AS u
  INNER JOIN dbo.Access AS a
    ON u.Access = a.ID
) AS keep
  ON u.ID = keep.ID
 AND a.AccessRank = keep.AccessRank
;
```

It is implied that `AccessRank` contains unique rankings only.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete the row for each id that first has access 5 and the rest ordered, then do:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id
                                     order by (case when access = 5 then -1 else access end)
                                    ) as seqnum
      from table t
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum = 1;
```

If you only want to do this when there is more than one record for the `id`:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id
                                     order by (case when access = 5 then -1 else access end)
                                    ) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from table t
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum = 1 and cnt > 1;
```

EDIT:

If you want to delete everything except one row according to your precedence rules:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id
                                     order by (case when access = 5 then -1 else access end)
                                    ) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from table t
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum < cnt;
```

Comment: Are you sure this addresses their survivorship rules?

Comment: The question says `access = 5` should be treated as lowest.

Comment: @MarkSowul . . . The OP explicitly states "delete the ID with the lowes Access value", so I would argue that the condition is rather ambiguously phrased.  But given the comments in the code, I changed it to delete the higher ones first.

Comment: @billinkc . . . Actually, I am more confident now.  Very confusingly phrased.

Answer (score 1):

Sample Access table:

```
|id|access|
-----------
|1 |  1   |
|1 |  2   |
|1 |  5   |
|2 |  1   |
|2 |  3   |
```

On running the below query:

```
DELETE a 
FROM acc a
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT row= ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY  (CASE WHEN ACCESS=5 THEN 0 ELSE ACCESS  END) DESC), * FROM acc) b
ON a.id = b.id AND a.access = b.access 
WHERE b.row > 1
```

The result is:

```
|id|access|
|1 |  2   |
|2 |  3   |
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be the fastest and most portable solution as it allows an index to be used on `Access` and uses standard SQL.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9fa87/6)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([ID] int, [Access] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([ID], [Access])
VALUES
    (1, 5),
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (2, 5),
    (2, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 5)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
delete t
from Table1 t
inner join (
    select ID, max(Access) as MaxAccess
    from Table1
    where Access <> 5
    group by ID
) pm on t.Access <> pm.MaxAccess
    and t.ID = pm.ID

select * from Table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9fa87/6/0)**:

```
| ID | ACCESS |
|----|--------|
|  1 |      2 |
|  2 |      2 |
|  3 |      5 |
```

Comment: Doesn't work if 5 is the only access. Add `, (3, 5)` to your `INSERT` statement and you'll see.

Comment: @MarkSowul It works correctly based on my understanding. The given `WHERE` clause is for `ID > 1`. The `(3, 5)` row gets deleted because `(2, 2)` has a higher permission value.

Comment: You're right, my test case is bad.  The question is admittedly confusing as hell.  Nevertheless, 5 should be treated as a minimum, but not necessarily excluded completely (`and Access <> 5`), right?

Comment: Actually I don't think my test case is bad.  I think it means, if the same ID is there more than once, remove the lowest (but 5 is actually lower than 1).  But again, the question is confusing.

Comment: @MarkSowul Are you the OP? I have updated my answer to find the highest access for each ID.